# iOS 6: UUIDString on iPhone 3GS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, uuid, iphone-3gs

I've been working on `ASIdentifierManager` framework to get the new `UUIDString`, the identifier should replace in iOS 6 the UDID, and can be stopped or not by the user for Settings.

Everything is ok on simulators and iPhone 4S, but on iPhone 3GS (it's iOS 6 updated!) I'm getting as UUIDString the following:
**00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000**

This is how I'm getting it:

```
if ([ASIdentifierManager sharedManager])        
    NSLog(@"%@", [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString]);
```

Does anyone know why? Have you encountered this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to this article

http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/27/source-apples-udid-replacement-for-advertisers-in-ios-6-is-broken/

there are serious problems with the new advertising identifier in iOS 6. It is claimed that on devices that were updated to iOS 6 via Wi-Fi, the advertising identifier contains only zeros.

According to that article, the problem does not occur on devices that were updated via iTunes.

Even if that does not solve your problem, it might help to explain it.